# Write datasets to combined xls file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have got a Scala script which writes a great deal of `csv` files with e.g. file names: "dog-species", "dog-weight", "cat-species", "cat-params" and so one. Would like to change the behaviour of the script to combine a datasets into bigger `xls` files with additional "info" sheet, which will contains some introductory details. Expected result:

- file "dog.xls" with sheets: "info", "species", "weight", ...
- file "cat.xls" with sheets: "info", "species", "params", ...

So my approach would be to use a conditional logic: when I proceed "dog-species" dataset, i check if the file "dog.xls" exists. If file exists I append the file "dog.xls" with new "species" sheets. If file doesn't exists I create a new "dog.xls" file with the "info" sheet and after that append with the "species" sheets.

Any idea about the possible Scala/Java libraries or ways to deal with the issue? I use Scala 2.10.5, Java 1.8, Spark 1.6.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Potential resolution is an spark-excel (com.crealytics.spark.excel library) which is a kind of wrapper for the Apache POI Java library, but unfortunately i's supported by the Spark version 2.+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark you can write CSV-s but not XLS files. 
I suggest that try to write CSV-s than merge them by your logic with https://poi.apache.org/

If you don't have huge datasets which I think it is the case (you don't store huge dataset in XLS) than you can just collect them and write the XLS.

Comment: Think merging the existing csv files will be easier solution. Do you know any good example presented on the internet maybe?